# Issue with showing all videos from DB (QuerySet object has no attribute)

Tags: python, django

I am uploading a video file to my webpage, which I can also play. However, the moment I want to show all the video files on different page and play them, I get:

AttributeError at /all_videos

QuerySet object has no attribute 'videofile'

I can't figure out what I am doing wrong. Models.py:

```
models.py
class VideoModel(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
videofile = models.FileField(upload_to='videos/', null=True, verbose_name="")

def __str__(self):
    return self.name + ": " + str(self.videofile)
```

Views.py:

```
views.py
class ShowVideosView(View):
def get(self, request):  
    form = VideoForm()
    lastvideo = VideoModel.objects.last()
    videofile = lastvideo.videofile
    return render(request, 'videos.html', {'videofile': videofile, 'form': form})


def post(self, request):
    form = VideoForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None) 
    lastvideo = VideoModel.objects.last()
    videofile = lastvideo.videofile
    form = VideoForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        name = form.cleaned_data['name']
        videofile = form.cleaned_data['videofile']
        new_video = VideoModel(name=name, videofile=videofile)
        new_video.save()

    context = {'videofile': videofile, 'form': form}
    return render(request, 'videos.html', context)

class ListOfVideosView(View):
def get(self, request):
    all_videos = VideoModel.objects.all()
    videofile = all_videos.videofile
    context = {'all_videos': all_videos, 'videofile': videofile}
    return render(request, 'all_videos.html', context)
```

all_videos.html:

```
all_videos.html
{% for video in all_videos %}
<video width='400' controls>
      <source src='{{MEDIA_URL}}{{videofile}}' type='video/mp4'
 Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Please add ***complete error traceback***

Comment: File "/home/borys/Desktop/borys_works/blog_django/src/posts/views.py", line 168, in get
    videofile = all_videos.videofile
AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'videofile'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is just what it looks like `all_videos` isn't an instance of `VideoModel`, so you can't just get the same attributes off of it.

```py
class ListOfVideosView(View):
    def get(self, request):
        all_videos = VideoModel.objects.all()
        videofile = all_videos.videofile  # This is the line where your error is getting raised.
        context = {'all_videos': all_videos, 'videofile': videofile}
        return render(request, 'all_videos.html', context)
```

What it looks like you're trying to do is access the `videofile` attribute of each `VideoModel` in the queryset. If that's correct changing your video list view and HTML to look something like this might help.

*views.py*

```py
class ListOfVideosView(View):
    def get(self, request):
        all_videos = VideoModel.objects.all()
        context = {'all_videos': all_videos}
        return render(request, 'all_videos.html', context)
```

*all_videos.html*

```
{% for video in all_videos %}
  <video width='400' controls>
    <source src='{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ video.videofile }}' type='video/mp4'>
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
  </video>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank you for your time and effort! It did help, I hope great things will await you in your future :)